# XUL IFRAME with FACEBOOK LIKE button

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox-addon, facebook-like, xul

Is it possible to create dynamically addressed LIKE button in XUL ?

Need to place it on XUL OVERLAY toolbar.

My idea is about IFRAME addressing like_button.html in chrome:// and changing src param inside. But there is javascript interaction with button, which can be problem, isn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know there won't be any problem in changing the parameters inside or outside using JavaScript and XUL.  Using DOM you can manipulate anything & you can create any elements dynamically in XUL JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Dynamically_modifying_XUL-based_user_interface
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Document_Object_Model
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Modifying_a_XUL_Interface
http://mb.eschew.org/15

These links will be more helpful for you to go on!!!!

Comment: thanks but problem is that button is created by javascript, I need to check if user is logged into facebook and if he liked that page already. I can't obviously do it without connection to JS FCB SDK and appID, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are correct. As I said before you can create any element using DOM JS is possible but regarding the verification system you need to link all the JS files with the FB SDK.

Comment: and that's what this question is about. How to create LIKE button with all its behavior in XUL in overlay (toolbar) in FF, with knowledge that LIKE button address is changeable via Javascript.

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Do_Not_Track_Field_Guide/Introduction/What_does_tracking_mean

Comment: You can bind any button in XUL overylay. For exmaple: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<overlay id="FacebookBlocker-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
 <script type='application/x-javascript' src='chrome://facebookblocker/content/fbblock.js'></script>
</overlay> You can refer this: http://mb.eschew.org/15

Comment: I hope you have found your solution. Thank you accepting my answer.